# Meaning of $\sim$ with a point?

Tags: notation

In a report, I wanted to write something like this:

For large $n$, we get

$$ x_n \sim \chi^2_p.$$

And a corrector in his corrections added a point on the $\sim$. I understand that the way I wrote it is considered wrong, because what I actually meant is that when $n$ tends to infinity, $x_n$ follows a chi-square distribution or that if $n$ is large, the distribution of $x_n$ is well approximated by a chi-square distribution. I assume $\dot{\sim}$ means "approximate the distribution well" but I have never seen this notation and I have searched a little bit but found nothing.

So what does $\dot{\sim}$ mean in this context if this notation even exists?

Comment: Ask the corrector?

Comment: Yes I will the next time I see him, but I would also like to avoid too "exotic" notations which could confuse the reader, so I just want to check if I am the only one who has never seen this notation and maybe rewrite my sentence to use more "normal" notations if not